# Show that there exists a $t \in [0, 1]$ such that $\alpha(f) =f(t)$ for all $f \in C_\mathbb{R}[0, 1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Suppose $\alpha$ is a nonzero multiplicative linear functional on $C_\mathbb{R}[0, 1]$. Show that there exists a $t \in [0, 1]$ such that $\alpha(f) =f(t)$ for all $f \in C_\mathbb{R}[0, 1]$.

I approached this by contradiction. I defined $g_t(x) = f_t(x) - \alpha(f_t)$ such that when I apply $\alpha$ to it, I get $0$ with $g_t(t) \ne 0$. I take a finite subcover of $[0,1]$ where each open set is centered around a $t$. I then define $G(x) = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty (g_{t_j}(x))^2$ (note that $G \ne 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$). I want to apply $\alpha$ to $G$ to get $0$, and then get a contradiction with $1 = \alpha(1) = \alpha(G \frac{1}{G}) = \alpha(G) \alpha(\frac{1}{G})$, but I don't know if I can apply $\alpha$ to an infinite sum. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your argument is good since you actually don't have an infinite sum:

After defining $g_t$ for each $t\in [0,1]$ there is an open neighbourhood $U_t$  of $t$ such that $g_t$ is never zero on $U_t$. Then you choose a $\textbf{finite}$ subcover $U_{t_1},...,U_{t_n}$, define $G=\sum_{i=1}^ng_{t_i}^2$ and conlude as  suggested.

Comment: Yes, by continuity. Oh, it's finite. Of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Nice!

Here's a more direct approach.

- $\alpha (f) = \alpha(1 f ) = \alpha(1)\alpha(f)$.  Therefore

$$ (*)\quad \alpha(1) =1,$$

because $\alpha$ is not identically zero.

- If $f\ge 0$

$$ (**) \quad 0 \le \alpha (\sqrt{f})^2 = \alpha(f).$$

- Since $0\le \|f\|_\infty-f$, it follows that

$$ (***) \quad  |\alpha(f)| \le \alpha (\|f\|_\infty) = \|f\|_\infty.$$

- By  $(**)$, $\alpha(x) \ge 0$, and then  by $(***)$, $\alpha (x) \in [0,1]$. Therefore by the intermediate value theorem there exists $x_0$ satisfying

$$ \alpha (x) = x_0.$$

This, along with $(*)$, linearity and multiplicative property imply

$$\alpha (p) = p(x_0),$$

whenever $p$ is a polynomial.

- As polynomials are dense in $C[0,1]$, it follows that for every $f$, there exists a polynomial $P_n$ such that $\| f-P_n\|_\infty \le \frac1n$. Thus

$$ |\alpha(f) - f(x_0) | = \underset{\le \frac {1}{n}}{\underbrace{ |\alpha (f) - \alpha(P_n) |}} + \underset{=0}{\underbrace{|\alpha(P_n) - P_n (x_0)|}} + \underset{\le \frac 1n}{\underbrace{| P_n (x_0) - f(x_0)|}},$$

with first inequality on RHS is due to $(***)$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to call $x_0= \alpha ( x)$, and then proceed from there?

Comment: yes, as long as you can justify that this is a number in  $[0,1]$, and that's part of the reason why we need the first bullets (perhaps you assume their validity from prior results. I tried to give a complete picture).

Comment: I really like this answer! Im just a little bit confused of how the intermediate value theorem comes into play. Do i miss something?

Comment: If  we take $f(x)=x$, then $\alpha(f)$ is a real number between $0$ and $1$.  The intermediate value theorem (not really necessary in this trivial case) guarantees that for this $f$ there is $x_0$ such that $\alpha(f)=f(x_0)$.